# How to unit test a class that depends on a class with a MASSIVE public interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

So I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application. One of my model classes depends on the Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) API provided by Microsoft.

I can't think of a good way to unit test this model class. 
The main two approaches I can think of are:

1) Write a stub of all the WSUS interfaces I use. The main drawback here is that these would be massive stubs. There are an enormous amount of methods in these interfaces. I don't have any paid tools at hand to speed up the task, either. I'm just using Nunit.

2) Write a new interface in place of every WSUS interface that I use. Only declare the methods that I use in my model class. Classes will then implement these interfaces which just call the appropriate method from the WSUS API. Then when I write my stubs, I only have to implement the methods I use (probably saving me 99% of the methods). The main drawback here is that whenever I change my model to use new methods from the WSUS API, I have to update my stub with new methods and also my wrapper classes.

Both seem like somewhat naive approaches. But I can't think of anything else.
What should I do??

Comment: Did you think about using a mocking framework? (such as Moq)

Comment: Are you using an interface and not implementing all of the methods?

Comment: @Dirnthelord I thought about using a mocking framework, but I was not sure if it would really solve the issue. And think it makes more sense in my case to test the output behaviour, not that a certain sequence of methods are called.

Comment: There are written whole books on how to test legacy code (in this context, when I say "legacy code" I mean code that was not designed to be testable), and I'm not sure this question fits the format of Stack Overflow. Here's a couple of videos to start with: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Unit-Testing-with-Microsoft-Fakes - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B331#fbid=

Comment: @Dismissile Not sure what you are asking. If I use the interfaces provided by Microsoft, it would be convenient to not implement all of the methods in my stubs, but that is not possible.

Comment: [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) or [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) is probably going to help you get around the "have to implement everything" monster, but it depends entirely on what your code is doing. If it ends up calling all the methods on the interfaces, you're going to have to provide meaningful stubs for all of those so that your code is happy.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So you're saying code that depends on an interface with many public methods is not designed to be testable?

Comment: In my opinion, correct. That you have an interface with many public methods means you've probably not followed [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) (in particular the S, Single Responsibility Principle, and I for Interface Segregation Principle) which makes the code hard(er) to test. Note that I'm not saying you can do anything about the Microsoft interface, but do you really depend on the whole thing?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen To be clear, it is Microsoft's interface that has many public methods. I'm being forced to depend on it. So it is not that I haven't followed SOLID.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree, I don't depend on the whole Microsoft interface, that is what I have been saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subclassing is a nice idea. If you realise that your class only uses a logical subset of the Windows Server Update Services API it would make sens to extract this interface as a facet of this huge dependency.

You can also easily substitute an object implementing an interface with a mock by using [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/). Just instantiate it in your tests

```
using NSubstitute;
var substitutedWSUS = Substitute.For<IWSUSInterface>();
```

NSubstitute is available on NuGet

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a mocking framework like @Dirnthelord suggests.  So your unit test should test the class you are implementing, not the WSUS API.  For unit tests, you should assume that the WSUS is implemented correctly, so you can use mock objects.  I like Moq, but there are other libraries available.

Martin Fowler has a good overview on stubs, fakes, and mocks. http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html